# javascript search is not giving correct value

Tags: javascript

I have following state var which contains states name. I am unable to search these keywords from search() function in Javascript.

```
var state = "Delhi, Rajasthan, Kolkata, Himachal Pradesh, Utter Pradesh";
```

I am searching keywords from the input box but not able to search with the key. Anything I want to change or translate to other function.

```
var subState = $("#inputVal").val("Rajasthan, Kolkata");
```

In Following Way I am Searching the values as follows

```
var n = state.search(subState);
```

If I alert or Console I am Getting -1 but not positive number.

Comment: What are you expecting `$("#inputVal").val("Rajasthan, Kolkata");` to give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) returns a jQuery object. Searching by that will surely return -1. What you want is closely related to this:

```
var state = "Delhi, Rajasthan, Kolkata, Himachal Pradesh, Utter Pradesh";
var subState = "Rajasthan, Kolkata";

$("#inputVal").val(subState);
var n = state.search(subState);
```

Comment: But that should match Because Rajasthan is present in the state.

Comment: @Samson -- in your code, `subState` will not be a string, but a jquery object (please read the docs). You can't match a string with a jquery object.

Comment: If I select it from javascript? had that become String, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value with `val("Rajasthan, Kolkata")`, you should do `val()` to obtain the value like this:

```
var subState = $("#inputVal").val();
```